# Blender Camera tracking frame invisible

Tags: mesh, camera, tracking

I've solved a camera tracking with 2 images, in Blender 2.83 LTS

In solved camera view, frame 0, I add a Sphere mesh.

When I advance to frame 1, I can see no Sphere mesh.

How to see the mesh in frame 1 ?

[image]
: frame 0
[image]
: frame 1 : same viewport window with just Right arrow key pressed to go from frame 0 to 1 : the mesh (the sphere in orange) is only available in frame 0

Comment: Hard to tell without more info. Is the camera pointing in the same direction in frame 1?

Comment: The direction is opposite, but big zoom out would reveal back meshes.

Comment: You are right ! I believed zoom-out was enough, but you have to see from another point of view (above for instance), to see that it was not in camera field. Thanks [SOLVED]